# Table display issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I got a table with 2 nested tables inside that display my two repeaters. My repeaters display Home and office addresses respectively. The problem is that whenever I add a new record in one repeater, the other repeater table's display gets messed up. Like if I add a record in rpt1 , then table for rpt1 moves up and table for rpt2 goes down..ie the headers do not display in one single line . They move up and down when records are added or deleted. WHat I want is these headers to be fixed so if I add new records or delete records, the headings of both repeaters display on the same line...How do I fix this ? Hope its not confusing.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
            <td width="50%">
              <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddAddress" runat="server">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" OnItemCommand="rpt1_ItemCommand" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_OnItemDataBound">

                 <HeaderTemplate>                              
                   <table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tr>
                 <td colspan="5" class="linegrey">
                       </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="lgrey">
                       <td>
                           Address1
                      </td>

                       <td>
                           City
                       </td>
                        <td>
                          State
                       </td>

                       <td>
                         IsDefault
                       </td>
                       <td>
                         Actions
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td colspan="5" class="dots">
                   </tr>
             </HeaderTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr>
                    <td>

                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddressB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address1")%>' CommandName="DisplayAddressB" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddID") %>' CausesValidation=false></asp:LinkButton>

                    </td>

                     <td>
                       <%# Eval("City")%>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <%# Eval("State")%>
                    </td>

                    <td>

                     <%-- Visible='<%# Eval("IsDefault")%>'--%>

                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDefaultB" Text="Set as Default" CommandName="SetDefaultB" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AddID") + "," + Eval("IsB") %>'
                      CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# Eval("IsDefault")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                      <asp:Label ID="labelDefaultB" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("IsDefault")%>'></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkAdd" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddID") %>'
                      CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.gif" Width="14" Height="14" ToolTip="Edit"></asp:ImageButton>
                      &nbsp;  
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDel" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddID") %>'
                      CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Delete.gif" Width="14" Height="14" ToolTip="Delete"></asp:ImageButton>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
            </asp:Panel>
           </td>
           <td>
             <asp:Panel ID="pnlSping" runat="server">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpt12" OnItemCommand="rpt12_ItemCommand" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptSpping_OnItemDataBound">
                     <HeaderTemplate>
                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                             <tr>
                               <td colspan="5" class="linegrey">
                               </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="lgrey">
                                 <td>
                                   Address1
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                   City
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                   State
                                   </td>
                                   <td>
                                    IsDefault
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                     Actions
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td colspan="5" class="dots">
                                  </tr>
                         </HeaderTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddressS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address1")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddID") %>' CommandName="DisplayAddressS" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                                     </td>

                                     <td>
                                     <%# Eval("City")%>
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                      <%# Eval("State")%>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDefaultS" Text="Set as Default" CommandName="SetDefaultS" runat="server" Visible=true CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AddID") + "," + Eval("IsS") %>'
                                        CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Label ID="labelDefaultS" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible=true></asp:Label>
                                       </td>
                                       <td>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkAdd" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddID") %>'
                                        CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.gif" Width="14" Height="14" ToolTip="Edit"></asp:ImageButton>
                                        &nbsp; 
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDel" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AddID") %>'
                                         CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Delete.gif" Width="14" Height="14" ToolTip="Delete"></asp:ImageButton>
                                        </td>
                                       </tr>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                              <FooterTemplate>
                                 </table>
                              </FooterTemplate>
                          </asp:Repeater>
                      </asp:Panel>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css attribute valign and set its value to top like this `<td width="50%" valign="top">`.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddAddress" runat="server">
                        ......
                    </asp:Panel>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSping" runat="server">
                        ......
                    </asp:Panel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: do I need to set this valign property for ALL the tds ?

Comment: Hey it got fixed...Thanks ! :D

Comment: nice that it worked but I agree with Dave that instead of repeating entire table you its a good practice to repeat a single row.

Answer (score 1):

For headers look to use the [`<th>`](http://w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_th.asp) element, this will keep them at the top of the table.

Put the `<table>` tags you do have outside your repeater controls, make sure the repeater only renders a single row and the same for the header.

Unless you have good reason consider just wrapping the two tables in `<div>` tags as nested tables really don't work ideally for layout.