# max length validation check

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my table in the DB, I have these data types for some of its columns..

```
Address1 nvarchar(200)
Address2 nvarchar(200)
City nvarchar(200)
State nvarchar(200)
```

Now in my aspx page I need to display this data in text boxes. What should be the max length
for the text boxes for Address1 text box, Address2 textbox, City's text box and state's according to what I have in my DB ?

How do I apply the max length validation check on these text boxes in my page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YEs, stick to what you have in your database, otherwise you might get truncation issues.

Have a look at [TextBox.MaxLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: What do I set MaxLength= ?? if in the DB data type is nvarchar(200)
?? Like what do I write in my markup??

Comment: Set the MaxLength property to the value (200) of the size of the specific field in the database.

Comment: like this ? <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd1" TabIndex="9" runat="server" class="textbox" MaxLength=200></asp:TextBox>

Comment: MaxLength="200". it should be in Quotes. check the link I provided.

Comment: What is the maxlength of varchar(200) ? like how many characters can it contain ?

Comment: Well, as you specify *varchar(200)* will have between 0 and 200 chars. So the Maximum is what you specified, 200.

Comment: I am displaying the 2  Addresses in my reapeater like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273709/table-display-issue ..If I use even over 50 characters for Address field..it completely screws up the look of my table inside repeater! Like it wud increases the width of the table and mess up the page display..But I need to use DataType as set in the DB only..What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The max length validation of your controls should match you max lenght of the fields in the data base.

The easiest way to do validation in your aspx page is through the validation controls.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx